# Growth bounds for solutions of variational problems

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, calculus-of-variations

Is there any good literature that mainly focus on quantitative estimates of solutions to variational problems? Take for example a generic 1-d variational problem such as wishing to choose a function $u$ in order to minimise the following functional,
$$ \int_\Omega f(x,u(x),u'(x))dx,$$
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$. It is my experience that most books either focus on delving deep into specific problems or rather study general existence, uniqueness and regularity theorems. Say we could prove there exists a unique $C^2(\Omega)$ solution of the above minimisation problem so that the strong form Euler-Lagrange equations are satisfied. Often times if your problem is somewhat general, directly analysing the solution via the Euler-Lagrange equations is just not tractable.

I would be very interested in any references that try to obtain quantitative estimates on solutions via methods not associated with analysing the Euler-Lagrange equations directly. Even simple questions like does $u\to 0 $ as $x \to \infty$, or is $u$ (or $u'$) bounded, are of interest.

This question is intentionally general as what I'm really looking for is some possible references for such kind of problems rather than an answer to a specific problem.

Comment: This is usually established *a priori* via restricting $u$ to lie in some space of decaying functions or constraining the value of $u$ on some boundary set. Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the solution space I am able to show existence and uniqueness for in my particular problem is a weighted Sobolev space , but this does not give you very much information regarding the quantitative behaviour of the solution. I can additionally prove my solution is $C^2$ and bounded but this doesn't directly give my any indication of a particular growth bound (which is really what I'm after).

Comment: If it lies in a Sobolev space on an unbounded domain, then the integrability of $u$ and its derivatives automatically give some decay estimates.

Comment: Yes this is a good point thank you, also having read your comments it has made me realise what I would really like is a lower bound on the decay rate, i.e I would like to be able to say the solution is decaying no faster than exponential.

Comment: In that case, I think that you would have to rely on asymptotics of the Euler-Lagrange equation or something.